# GestureRecognizer on Span doesn't fire when clicked on

Tags: xamarin.forms

The following code doesn't work:

```
var fs = new FormattedString();

fs.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = "\n\n" });

var telSpan = new Span { Text = "Hi Mum!" };

telSpan.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
{
   Command = new Command(() =>
   {
      // ...
   })
});

fs.Spans.Add(telSpan);
```

If I put a **TapGestureRecognizer** on the parent **Label** then that fires with no problems.

I have a Span with a **GestureRecognizer** elsewhere that's declared in XAML and it works fine.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Did you call the method `label.FormattedText = fs;`? It works fine on my side.You can share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Yes, the text shows, and it's highlighted if I change the color.

Comment: The issue seems to be that the span won't respond to a tap if it's on the third row of text or later. Try adding another span before the span in the question and set its text to two line breaks.

Comment: If you have solved it, you can post the solution and accept it :)

Comment: I haven't solved it. I need the link to be further down than the second row. This issue doesn't affect my other similar (XAML) usage and yet I've got nothing but a label appearing on the screen. It makes no sense so I think I will give up a use a separate label.

Comment: You can share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: I've added a new line to the code snippet in the answer. See if that's clickable if it's assigned to a label.

Comment: It works fine on my side, the command will be invoked when I tap the `Hi Mum`.

Comment: Thanks, that's reassuring. I have used an additional label and it works.

Comment: You can post the solution and accept it  .Which will help more people :)

Comment: I don't think it's a solution - it's a capitulation brought on by scarcity of time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200302/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-ian-warburton).

Comment: @IanWarburton, i was curious about your issue, and spend some time trying to reproduce it, without success. I would advice either you provide more information, or delete the post. If your post a small complete sample where the issue can be reproduces, i would be glad to set a Boutny to call attention on the issue and find a solution!

Comment: @Julipan I think it's an odd bug that's not easy to reproduce.

Comment: @IanWarburton, i am fair new to SO, but i would imagine that if you can not reproduce the issue yourself, then the best would be that you delete the post. I spent some time trying to figure out what could be wrong... and now i feel i just wasted my time... I am afraid i wont be the last... Just my opinion.

Comment: @Julipan Your message will be a warning to those who take up the challenge that they may well be wasting their time.

Comment: I was facing the same issue but the missing part at my side that I was tapping other spans which were not attached with gestures. Your code is perfectly fine just check your span which you are using to tap :( :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding TapGestureRecognizers to each span in a Label. In this example, I then add the Label to a StackLayout.

```
var fs = new FormattedString();
foreach(var sentence in paragraph) 
{
     var span = new Span
     {
          Text = sentence.Message,
          TextColor = Color.FromHex("#222"),
          FontSize = 16,
     };
                
     span.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
     {
          Command = new Command(i =>
          {
               // On double tap the sentence Id will be written to the console.
               Console.WriteLine(i);
          }),
          CommandParameter = sentence.Id,
          NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 // removing this line will default number of taps to 1 
     });

     fs.Spans.Add(span);
}
// remove LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap if unnecessary.
someStackLayout.Children.Add(new Label { LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap, FormattedText = fs });
```